# Как уставновить прослушку к CursorAdaper?

Tags: java, android, cursoradaper

```
listCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.help_text,
            _cursor,
            new String[]{SqlHelperArticle._ARTICLE_NAME, SqlHelperArticle._AUTHOR },
            new int[]{R.id.helper_text_article, R.id.helper_text_author}, 0);

    _articleList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listArticles);
    _articleList.setAdapter(_listCursorAdapter);
```

Как мне привязать к этому адаптеру прослушку что бы при нажатии на елемент вызывалась вторая Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вбиваете в гугл

> [android cursoradapter onitemclick](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20cursoradapter%20onitemclick)

2. Идёте по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581460/cursoradapter-onitemclick-of-listview)
3. Копируете себе код:

   ```
   _articleList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
   {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) 
       {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);    
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
   ```